# How to change where Pandas looks for its own files (specifically parsers.pyx)?

Tags: python, pandas, directory, path

I'm trying to practice working with pandas. I'm having trouble importing csv files with pandas.read_csv(). I keep getting an error saying "Unable to open parsers.pyx (Error: File not found (C:\Users\me...)) The issue is that this path is where my files are stored, not the pandas files.

I've tried changing the launch.json for VS Code to use a different default path but that had no effect. I have also tested the path for importing the csv file using numpy, so the issue isn't there.

```
`import pandas as pd
cols = ["bedrooms", "bathrooms", "area", "zipcode", "price"]
inputPath = "My Files/HousesInfo.txt"
df = pd.read_csv(inputPath, sep=" ", header=None, names=cols)
df.head()`
```

Comment: Can you post the full error that is returned?

Comment: VS Code had a pop up that said "Unable to open 'parsers.pyx': Unable to read file (Error: File not found (c:\users\david\documents\...\my files\pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx))."

Comment: Hmm, without seeing the full error it's hard to guess what the issue might be. Unless something went wrong when you installed pandas, I'm going to guess that you aren't giving `pd.read_csv` the correct file path. I would try running it with the full path for an example csv file to see if that works, or if the error changes.

Comment: im getting the same error, pandas is looking in the dir where the file your using is and not in pandas files.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same problem. It's not a complete solution, but I found that calling `open()` on the pathname and using that with read_csv works in my case:

```
pd.read_csv(open(inputPath), sep=" ", header=None, names=cols)
```